# Am I under leveled?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm on the quest, 'Elder Knowledge' and I'm level 13. I made my way through most of the dungeon but when I met with the Dwarven Centurion, I got my ass kicked every time I tried to fight it.

Knowing I was able to, I just ran past it and continued through the dungeon running past all the enemies. (I tried to fight but now they're all kicking my ass.) I don't know if this is the intention of the design or if I'm just extremely under leveled for this quest.

Answer (score 5):

[The UESP wiki recommends **level 18** for this quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elder_Knowledge). To help make the quest easier you could:

- Lower your game difficulty
- Get better gear
- Level up on other quests/fights
- Make/buy potions

The quest is fairly long, so you may wish to do this before continuing with the dungeon. However if you're a long way into a dungeon already, I believe it is possible (but not intended) to run past a lot of the enemies.

Comment: There are more powerful enemies in Blackreach, and it's huge and tricky to navigate, so I'd second doubling back and trying this later. Focusing on stealth attacks against centurions and running away until they stop searching for you may help, but other enemies may still be a problem. Fortunately, though, the very end is a puzzle, not a boss fight.

Comment: @JohnLaviolette Once you get to Blackreach I believe you can exit to Skyrim and then easily come back to it when you're leveled up to do the stuff you need to do there, so doubling back might not be necessary if OP is quite far in, although I would still recommend it if they're nearer the start.

Comment: As I recall, you can exit to Skyrim via an elevator at the bottom of Alftand, immediately before you enter Blackreach. But the way back down will be closed off if you leave to gain more levels, so you need to go back through a (partially?) respawned Alftand to get to Blackreach again. Even if yoou can't, getting back out now is a better choice.

Comment: @JohnLaviolette Doesn't the lever on the inside allow you to permenantly open the gate and use the lift to get back down in the future?

Comment: Definitely not. I've gone back after a long absence and found it locked. In fact, if i enter Blackreach another way, I can't get into Alftand.

Comment: @JohnLaviolette Huh. I thought that was pretty much the point of the lever, although I guess I haven't really used the lift again after being gone for long.

Comment: The area with the level will reset after a number of days.  You CAN return to it within that period, but not after when it resets.